# How to install g++ or c++ without paying for xcode?

Tags: xcode

I need to install node.js on my new Mac and it requires having c++ or g++ compiler installed.
How do I get one without paying for xcode?

Comment: Xcode is a free download for all members of the iOS and Mac Developer Programs.

Comment: It's only XCode 4 that you need to pay for - if you're not a paying developer. XCode 3.2.6 can be downloaded for free.

Comment: XCode 4 is less than the price of a latté.

Comment: @Ian C. - Stop shopping at Starbucks, then.

Comment: @Ian C. in the mist of *off-topicness*, I'd like to point out (as someone who speaks a semi-decent italian) that the coffee you're referring to, is spelled *caffè latte*, and is also sometimes incorrectly spelled latté or lattè. ;) Regarding the price of Xcode, although I agree with the *-should not affect you-* cheap price of Xcode, the OP asked for a free way to get C++ compiler, which, cheap or not, is a valid question. I still think that Xcode and dev tools are a hell of a package for under 5 dollars. But to each his own.

Comment: @Martin: http://theoatmeal.com/blog/apps :)

Comment: Note that that Xcode has become free again see the Mac App Store - most of these answers are now out of date

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can still download Xcode 3.x for free with a free developer account. Xcode 3 comes with the GCC 4.2, LLVM-GCC 1.5 and LLVM 1.5 so everything you need to compile C++, C and ObjC code.

(Remark: LLVM 1.5 can't compile C++ code, so you have to switch back to LLVM-GCC or GCC for this.)

Comment: Note that only Xcode 4.1 (I think) on Lion had to be paid for all other versions are free wether from App Store or Developer downloads

Answer (score 8):

Just to be complete - [Xcode](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12) 4.1.1 is free on the App Store but it requires Lion which implies a recent hardware purchase or paying for the upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

### [OSX GCC Installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)

> Downloading and installing the massive Xcode installer is a huge hassle if you just want GCC and related tools.
>
> The osx-gcc-installer allows you to install the essential compilers from either pre-built binary packages or helps you create your own installer.

First mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/28427/14994) by [Dancek](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/12443/dancek)

Answer (score 2):

You could get gcc for MacOSX from Apples Open Source site: http://opensource.apple.com/release/developer-tools-40/
It doesn't come with any instructions though.

(I think gcc is suitable, please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: And what exactly is supposed to build GCC without GCC?

Comment: @JustSid unicorns, clearly.

Comment: @ Martín Marconcini: Ohh, I see. I always wondered why they shipped my iMac with a unicorn, now it makes perfectly sense.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realise that they don't also provide the binaries for it onthere.

Answer (score 2):

The Mac comes with software DVDs--one of those has Xcode. You can install it from there.

Comment: This is pretty much the fastest way to get Xcode installed, albeit at the cost of getting a -possibly- outdated version. Since Apple curiously doesn't offer "upgrades", your (also free, as correctly pointed out in JustSid's answer) Xcode 3.x download will be a full 4GB++ package.

Comment: For the unknown reason I can see only "Bundled Software" disk in the package and it didn't seem to contain xcode when I've tried to install.. So I've gone with the download solution. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: This is the best way to bootstrap the latest GCC from open source if you can't or won't get a free Xcode 3 download by enrolling as a free Apple developer.

Answer (score -1):

XCode does NOT come with the latest GCC and G++ (it comes with 4.2), so you still need to do your own install if you want the latest features. Macports and GNU do NOT provide sufficient instructions. So, it remains a mystery.

You can download XCode or find it on your install CD. That will give you you the older GCC/G++. Once you have that, you can download the latest GCC.

US, Tampa: http://mirrors-us.seosue.com/gcc/

BUT, how do you install??

All I know is..

1. Unzip the folder. It should be named    gcc-4.6.3  OR  gcc-4.7.3   etc.
2. Create a new folder ADJACENT to the gcc-4.6.3 folder, called     buidgcc
   (the   buildgcc   folder and   gcc-4.6.3   folder  live in the same place. Possibly in the folder     Developer/usr    )
3. Open a terminal (Applications->Utilities->Terminal)
4. Navigate to the   buildgcc     folder that you created
   **Terminal Commmands**
   cd ..      brings you UP 1 level(note space between  cd  and  ..  )
   ls         tells you what files & folders are in the folder you're in
   cd/foldername         lets you navigate into a folder
5. If you're in the    buildgcc    folder, type:
    ../gcc-4.6.3/configure
   WAIT.   Then type:
     make
   WAIT a very long time.

Sorry. Here is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Macports does supply instructions on how to install - I have done it often